# PHP Mysqli Calculation of retrieved values from database

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a db with 3 tables. Table A contains goods with descriptions and prices and so on. There 2 columns of prices: first price and sales price. Table B contains customer details and table C the orders. I print to page with "SELECT goods.*,customers.*, orders.* FROM goods,customers,orders WHERE...."
'customers' and 'orders' contain both a column for the bill number, so if a customer orders, there will be a new row in 'orders' for every item bought with the same bill number in the column. How can I show the order with the customer details and the bill number showing once only and then just listing the appropriate ordered items?
In order to calculate the total of an order, I did this:

```
    if(empty($row["PriceSale"])||$row["PriceSale"]=='0.00')
    {
       $Price=$row["Price"];
    }else{
       $Price=$row["PriceSale"];
    }

    $sum = 0;
    $amount = $row["Amount"];
    $NPrice = $Price*$amount; //for total of one item (per row)

    $sum    = ($sum + $NPrice); //if this line is not there, then the $total_sum will have no effect
    $sum    = number_format($sum,2);
```

Now when I do:

```
    $total_sum += str_replace(",", "", $sum);
```

then it calculates the price total, but it also shows me the 'Notice: Undefined variable: $total_sum....' When I do $totalsum=0 it will calculate wrong. So, how can this be done?

Comment: $totalsum=NULL;  . @ceyrslan  You doing a string operation. If you need a empty string, use $string ='';    **or**  $string = NULL;

Comment: You should look into using `BC Math` functions for precision math http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php

Comment: @ Subin Thomas Thank you, but I already tried that. And it will not do the calculation of all items, only the last one in the list.

Comment: When you say it calculates wrong, what do you mean? Can you give some example data?

Comment: I dont know if this is good but i solved it using this:

Comment: $default=NULL;
if(empty($Tsum)) {
    $Tsum = $default;
}